# Jenkins pass all environment variables to a script

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to plugin a custom python app into my Jenkins pipeline.  The app needs `ALL` of current `Environment Variables` to be passed in.

I can either provide them in via cli, or write all of them to a file in the workspace.  How would you solve this?

Is this a way out? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin or https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SharedObjects+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that any Jenkins plugin is required for your case.

If you call your python app from a script build step, all variables should be in the app's environment by default. If you need to save a dump of environment variables to a file, just use env/set commands depending on your OS.

Comment: Valid point, however, if you have a build pipeline, passing parameters/variables between jobs becomes problematic.